# aws SSL certificate not getting it to work on my load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, aws-application-load-balancer, godaddy-api

I have a load balancer, and I need a secure connection for it.
Currently if you access: https://myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/ it's unsecure connection.  For this I did the following:

- I went to AWS Certificate Manager, and generated the certificate (I've requested one, with email validation and all went well):

Domain: godaddydomanain.com
Status: Issued

The certificate was issued under the same region as the load balancer.

Coming back to my load balancer, I added a listener HTTPS:443.
For Forward to myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com HTTP - weight 1
With security policy ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08 (the default that was there)
Default SSL/TLS certificate: From ACM I selected the certificate created previously.

After this, when open https://myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/ I still see unsecure.

On my godaddy console I have in the DNS table:

**CNAME   www                  myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.   1 Hour**        - so when I access [www.godaddydomain.com](http://www.godaddydomain.com) its ok, unsecure but ok

**HTTPS   godaddydomain.com    myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.   1 Hour**        - I've added it just now (but it will take 48 hours to see something)

This should solve my issue to access godaddydomain.com with a secure connection?

Shouldn't I be able to see right now a secure connection when accessing **myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com**? I am afraid that I did something wrong.

[After 2 days update]: the certificate is approved. The https://godaddydomain.com is not working and the [www.godaddydomain.com](http://www.godaddydomain.com) and godaddydomain.com are still unsecure.

Please help

Comment: Is the certificate status "Issued" (green)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/` is not the domain name you created the certificate for. You have to go to `https://godaddydomanain.com` for the SSL certificate to work.

> Shouldn't I be able to see right now a secure connection when accessing myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com?

No. The SSL certificate is for a specific domain name. It only works for that specific domain name. It will never work with the `elb.amazonaws.com` domain name.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but on godaddy, I've added in the DNS table:

CNAME www myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.- so when I access www.godaddydomain.com its ok, unsecure but ok - this works

HTTPS godaddydomain.com myapp.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 1 Hour - this still shows if I try to access: www.godaddydomain.com - unsecure ,   https://godaddydomain.com/  - not working, godaddydomain.com - unsecure

Comment: Did you create the certificate for `godaddydomain.com` or `www.godaddydomain.com`, or both? One is a root domain, one is a subdomain. You have to be specific about that when you are creating the certificate.